# For menu item other than article - won't show page header H1

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, header-tags

When I have menu items (other than articles) and

```
Page Display -> Show Page Heading = YES
Page Display -> Page Heading = BlaBlaBla....
```

I do not see any Page Header. This works only if the menu item is an article!
Am I right and how to make appear Page Headers (with H1 tag) on any menu item (for any component)?

PS: saw this code in this forum:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)) : ?>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is up to each component to produce the display, and thus whether or not to include the page heading param from the menu item.  I have seen some templates also implement page titles too. You could of course make template overrides for all the component views, but I think that's a little impractical. If I was trying to get consistent menu param driven titles on every page for every component I would use a custom module and then hide all the headings I didn't wish to see.